# How to call CMS block

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block

I've created a widget, this widgets has a CMS block chooser on the block class I have the following function:

```
public function getCmsBlock()
{
    $blockId = $this->getData("block_id");
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $block   = $this->_blockFactory
                ->create()
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->load($blockId);

    return $block;
}
```

The `$this->_storeManager` class variable is an instant of `Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory` I realised that the load function is deprecated and the `setStoreId` doesn't really work.

What is the alternative for loading a CMS block programatically where I would be able to set the store ID and check if the CMS is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository` to get block by ID, like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository
 */
protected $blockRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository $blockRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository $blockRepository
) {
    $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
}

public function getBlockById($id, $storeId)
{
    $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($id)
        ->setStoreId($storeId);

    return $block;
}
```

In addition you can use the method `getList()` to get block like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository
 */
protected $blockRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
 */
protected $filterBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup
 */
protected $filterGroup;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface
 */
protected $searchCriteria;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository $blockRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository $blockRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
) {
    $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
    $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
    $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Block|null
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
protected function getBlockData()
{
    $block = null;
    $storeId = 0;
    $blockId = 'test-block';

    $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder->create()
            ->setField('store_id')
            ->setValue($storeId)
            ->setConditionType('eq'), // default value
        $this->filterBuilder->create()
            ->setField('identifier')
            ->setValue($blockId),
    ]);

    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
    $blocks = $this->blockRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);

    if ($blocks->getItems()) {
        /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
        $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($blockId);
    }

    return $block;
}
```

The `getList()` result should look like this:

[image: getList result]

and block looks as usual:

[image: block]

Comment: @AndréFerraz my solution does not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code,

```
        $blockId = 2;
        $html = '';
        if ($blockId) {
            $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
            $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
            $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);
            if ($block->isActive()) {
                //do your code here...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Like I said the load function is deprecated.

Comment: Load is used in magento 2.1 this function is given from magento cms core module

Comment: but is deprecated, which is not recommended to be used.